# Как найти символы на изображении на python с помощью библиотеки Pillow (PIL) Лучше без сторонних библиотек?

Tags: python, нейронные-сети, pillow, pil

Вот например есть изображение с номером автомобиля. Как мне найти каждый символ и сохранить его в файл png/jpg? Я гуглил в интернете, но нашел только как иноземный человек просил помочь ему сделать то что прошу и я. Но в примере используеться OpenCV, а я хотел бы знать как сделать это с помощью pillow.

Comment: Без `OpenCV` думаю вряд ли это возможно. Если только он не на известном заранее фиксированном месте. `Pillow` всё-таки не для таких задач.

Comment: ну вы конечно можете попробовать реализовать необходимый функционал на PIL... Но что-то мне подсказывает что через пару месяцев беспощадной и бессмысленной работы вы сдадитесь и начнете использовать готовые библиотеки. ;)

Comment: Наверное) Попробую реализовать это с OpenCV